# mvc 4 dropdownlist not function as it should

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

### The ViewData item that has the key 'WorkStations' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

This is the error im getting, I am getting the value that the droplist is sending, but when it try to add it to the data it just crashes and im getting the error that i wrote abow.

I have tried updating the html tag to

> @Html.DropDownList("WorkStations", (SelectList)ViewBag.WorkStations)

This is my model

```
namespace MvCfirstproject.Models
{
    [Table("WorkHoursModels")]
    public class WorkhoursModels
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Start { get; set; }
        public string Stop { get; set; }
        public string command { get; set; }
        public string Users { get; set; }
        public string WorkStations { get; set; }
       

    }
    [Table("WorkStations")]
    public class WorkHoursStation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string WorkStations { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Workstations { get; set; }
    }


    public class WorkhourDB : DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<WorkhoursModels> WorkHours { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WorkHoursStation> WorkStation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Controller

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.WorkStations = new SelectList(db.WorkStation, "WorkStations", "Workstations");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Default1/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(WorkhoursModels workhoursmodels)
    {
        if (workhoursmodels.command == "Users")
        {
            db.WorkHours.Add(workhoursmodels);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And this is my view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Users)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Users)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Users)
        </div>
     
     <div>
       @Html.DropDownList("WorkStations", String.Empty)
    </div>
              <p>
             <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.command)" value="User"/>

        </p>

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're view is strongly typed for the model `WorkhoursModels`

1. You don't need a viewbag because you're defining a IEnumerable in the properties of your model just change the Action passing the model to the view

   ```
   public ActionResult Create()
   {
         WorkhoursModels model = new WorkhoursModels();
         model.Workstations  = db.WorkStation.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.WorkStations , Value = x.Id.ToString() });
         return View(model);
   }
   ```
2. Use the properly helper

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, Model.Workstations, string.Empty)
   ```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, its all good althought i had to remove x.Id.toString() now it wont let me enter the create phase so i cant see what data its sending.

Comment: add a validation message for the dropdown and check if exits errors in the form

Comment: Why you remove the x.Id.toString()?? how your passing hte value of each element in the view?

Comment: Cuz im getting this compiling error 'int' does not contain a defention for 'toString' and no extension method 'toString accepting first argument

Comment: Added but instead of toString() type Id.ToString() and try

Comment: Yeah, ive tried that that way im getting a LINQ error 

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I fixed that already! 

An item with the same key has already been added.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: Yeah, thanks might do that! might also look over the code and see whats up with it.

Thanks!